# CListView pager doesn't work with custom CSqlDataProvider in Yii

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm trying to put together a report in Yii by using CListView. In my view I have two date pickers on a form to set data range for the report. Once I submit the form it returns with the first record properly but after I click on pager it renders my main page instead of the next record.

I guess the problem is that I define my data provider in controller only on form submission but I can't figure out how can I pass my data provider each time when pager is called. I tried to modify the `if` condition in my controller to check if `page` has been posted but it didn't work either. Do I need to use Ajax for that? Important that I would like both date pickers to be present on top of the form on all pages if possible.

Can somebody help me out?

My Controller:

```
    public function actionView()
    {
        $model=new Kivetes;
        $egyedi_etel_idk = array();
        $sqlProvider = array();
        if(isset($_POST['Kivetes']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Kivetes'];

            $count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT COUNT(osszerendeles.etel_id)
                      FROM `ff_etlap` etlap 
                        INNER JOIN `ff_etlap_osszerendeles` osszerendeles ON etlap.id = osszerendeles.etlap_id
                      WHERE etlap.datum >= '".$model->datum_tol."' AND etlap.datum <= '".$model->datum_ig."'
                      GROUP BY osszerendeles.etel_id")->queryScalar();

            $sql_egyedi_etel_idk = "SELECT osszerendeles.etel_id as 'etel_id'
                                    FROM `ff_etlap` etlap 
                                    CS  INNER JOIN `ff_etlap_osszerendeles` osszerendeles ON etlap.id = osszerendeles.etlap_id
                                    WHERE etlap.datum >= '".$model->datum_tol."' AND etlap.datum <= '".$model->datum_ig."'
                                    GROUP BY osszerendeles.etel_id";

            $sqlProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($sql_egyedi_etel_idk, array(
                    'keyField' => 'etel_id',
                    'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                    'pagination'=>array(
                            'pageSize'=>'1',
                    ),
            ));

        }

        $this->render('view',array('model'=>$model,
                                   'dataProvider'=>$sqlProvider));
    }

}
```

My View:

```
    <?php setlocale(LC_ALL, "hu_HU.UTF-8"); ?>

<div class="form">

    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'kivetes-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    )); ?>

    <?php
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $day_number = date('N', strtotime($today));
        $first_day = $day_number - 1;
        $last_day = 7- $day_number;
    ?>

    <fieldset>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'datum_tol'); ?>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
                        'name'=>'datepicker_tol',
                        'language'=>'hu',
                        'model'=>$model,
                        'attribute'=>'datum_tol',
                        // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
                        'options'=>array(
                            'showAnim'=>'slide',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
                            'dateFormat'=>'yy/mm/dd',
                            'showWeek' => 'true',
                            'minDate' => -$first_day,
                            'maxDate' => $last_day,
                        ),
              ));
        ?>

        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'datum_ig'); ?>
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker',array(
                        'name'=>'datepicker_ig',
                        'language'=>'hu',
                        'model'=>$model,
                        'attribute'=>'datum_ig',
                        // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
                        'options'=>array(
                            'showAnim'=>'slide',//'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
                            'dateFormat'=>'yy/mm/dd',
                            'showWeek' => 'true',
                            'minDate' => -$first_day,
                            'maxDate' => $last_day,

                        ),
              ));
        ?>

        </br>
        <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                            'type'=>'primary',
                            'label'=>'Listázás',
                            'url'=>'',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array('onclick' => '$("#kivetes-form").submit()'),
    )); ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->

<?php 
        if (!empty($model->datum_tol))
        {
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                    'itemView'=>'_kivetes',));
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pagination works using GET-method, so this `if(isset($_POST['Kivetes']))` will be false, you should use GET-method for your form.

```
if(isset($_GET['Kivetes']))
     {
```

And

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'kivetes-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'method'=>'get'
)); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. What you're referring to is my model (Kivetes) not the pagination. I looked after and it seems that there's no strait forward solution to my problem. It seems I need to write my own pager. I found this on the Yii community forum: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/25901-pagination-solution-simple-and-complex-ways/.